# getting value of radio buttons in the same group name

Tags: c#, asp.net

as a part of an exercise i'm attempting to do, its used for a parents meetings day, where i want to display a table of meetings, with a radio button next to the hour and so a student can login and 
embed himself to the time he wants.

so i have a table control which i build dynamically from the database **MeetingsTable** that has the columns:

- meetingHour
- meetingDate
- meetingPlace
- studentID

the code behind looks like this:
(some of it is in hebrew so ignore it)

```
public string error = "";//Initialize error string
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
    string fileName = "ParentsDayDB.accdb";
    string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Meetings";
    DataBindMeetingsTable(fileName, selectQuery);

}

protected void IDButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string studentID = IDTextBox.Text;
    string pattern = @"^\d{9}$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
    if (reg.IsMatch(studentID))
    {
        string fileName = "ParentsDayDB.accdb";
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE studentID = '" + studentID + "'";
        if (MyAdoHelper.IsExist(fileName, selectQuery))
        {
            DataTable table = MyAdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable(fileName, selectQuery);
            string studentName = (string)table.Rows[0]["studentName"];
            string studentClass = (string)table.Rows[0]["studentClass"];
            string parentName = (string)table.Rows[0]["parentName"];
            Student student = new Student(studentID, studentClass, studentName, parentName);
            Session["student"] = student;
            if ((bool)table.Rows[0]["isAdmin"] == true)
            {
                Session["isAdmin"] = "true";
            }
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            error = "<hr align=\"right\" width=\"230px\" /> תעדות הזהות לא קיימת";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error = "<hr align=\"right\" width=\"440px\" /> אנא הכנס תעודת זהות תקינה בעלת 9 ספרות";
    }
}


public void DataBindMeetingsTable(string fileName, string selectQuery)
{

    DataTable dt = MyAdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable(fileName, selectQuery);
    //הוספת הכותרות
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = "שעה";
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = "תאריך";
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = "מיקום";
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = "ת.ז. תלמיד";
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    MeetingsTable.Rows.Add(tr);

    //הוספת הנתונים לטבלה
    int numCols = dt.Columns.Count;
    int radioIndex = 1;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        tr = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
        {
            object item = dr.ItemArray[i];
            TableCell c = new TableCell();
            c.BorderWidth = 1;
            if (i == 0)//אם בתא צריך להיות כפתור של שעה
            {
                RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
                r.Text = item.ToString();
                r.AutoPostBack = true;
                r.GroupName = "radioButtonList";
                c.Controls.Add(r);
                c.CssClass = "radioButtonCell";
            }
            else //אם התא הוא רגיל ורק צריך להציג בו מידע
                c.Text = item.ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(c);
        }
        radioIndex++;
        MeetingsTable.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}

public string GetRadioValue(ControlCollection controls, string groupName)// return the value of the selected radio button, empty string if nothing is selected.
{
    // using Language Intergrated Query (LINQ) in order to find the radio button that is selected in the groupName.
    var selectedRadioButton = controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked);
    return selectedRadioButton == null ? string.Empty : selectedRadioButton.Attributes["Value"]; //trinary operator (shortcut of an if expresison)
}


protected void meetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string radioValue = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
    //string radioValue = GetRadioValue(form1.Controls, "radioButtonList");
    string radioValue = GetRadioValue(form1.Controls, "radioButtonList")
    if (!radioValue.Equals("")) // אם נבחרה שעה
    {
        string hour = radioValue;
        Student student = (Student)Session["Student"];
        string id = student.StudentID;
        if (MeetingHelper.Meet(hour, id))
            promptLabel.Text = "הפגישה נקבעה בהצלחה";
        else
            promptLabel.Text = "השעה שבחרת תפוסה, בחר שעה אחרת";
    }
    else
        promptLabel.Text = "בחר שעה";
}
```

the page will look like this: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfFEh.png)

The problem is when i hit the embed meeting button, it will not find the radio button that is selected, after debugging i have noticed there is a problem with the control collection that i am sending, so I tried sending this.Controls or just using Controls. neither helped.

While i could just use a Radio Button List control, and access the selected value attribute, I couldn't manage to display it the way i wanted to look, each radio button in a separate row with the other columns added to the generated table (or some other trick to make the same result).

I have all the using calls that are needed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

I really am frustrated at this, please enlighten me!

> The **MyAdoHelper class** is not really relevant for this problem because
>   it doesn't even get into the if statement in the button click call, so
>   i have excluded it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160594/event-handler-for-groupbox-with-radiobuttons-in-c-sharp

Comment: @viper yes, I have read that already, but when i try to add the event handler to the radiobuttons as so: r.OnCheckedChanged += ... I get an error that the control is inaccessible due to it's protection level.

Comment: Are you adding it in the correct class? It can be added in the `InitializeComponent()` section, otherwise, anywhere in the forms class.

Comment: @vipersassassin I really am not sure what you are talking about, could you further explain? You can see in my code i am adding the radiobutton in the call of the function 'DataBindMeetingsTable'

Comment: It would be added in prior to losing scope, so prior to the end of `if(i == 0){ }`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the selected radio button text in following way:

```
public string GetRadioValue(ControlCollection controls, string groupName)// return the value of the selected radio button, empty string if nothing is selected.
{
    // using Language Intergrated Query (LINQ) in order to find the radio button that is selected in the groupName.
    var selectedRadioButton = controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked);
    return selectedRadioButton == null ? string.Empty : selectedRadioButton.Text; //trinary operator (shortcut of an if expresison)
}
```

and call the method like

```
string text = GetRadioValue(form1.Controls, "RadioGroupName"); //where form1 is your container id.
```

and `asp:RadioButton` look like

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" Text="Text for radio button" runat="server" GroupName="RadioGroupName" />
```

Comment: please look at my code, this is what I have been trying to do, but it is not working for me..

Comment: the GetRadioValue always returns null, that is the problem i am looking to solve

Comment: I copied the same code from yours and modified this line                      (return selectedRadioButton == null ? string.Empty : selectedRadioButton.Text)

Comment: This method return the text of the selected radio button. Look at the calling of the method, I had the same issue while I use the code like yours but I replace  selectedRadioButton.Attributes["Value"] by selectedRadioButton.Text it works as expected. Only small change on your code  :)

Comment: hey raj I have tried it and that is surely not the problem, after debugging once again i realized i have a problem with the control collection that is sent into the GetRadioValue method.

Comment: What is the control collection i should send if, they are all in a separate table row? do i have to build a control collection each time, or should i just build a radiobuttonlist each time and avoid the linq.

Comment: Your aspx code should be inside  the form tag with runnet as server, you can use the Id of the form as your control container..

Comment: That is the way it is, my form is in a form tag with runat='server' but, it is not working as i described before

Answer (score 0):

After debugging i came to realization that I do not have a **control owner** or **control container** that contains all the radioButton Controls. 
therefore using LINQ is irrelevant, i have used the following code to get the radioValue of the selected radioButton in the Table control:

> ```
> public string GetRadioValue()
> {
>     string radioValue = "";
>     foreach (TableRow dr in MeetingsTable.Rows)
>     {
>         int countControls = dr.Cells[0].Controls.Count;
>         if (countControls != 0)
>         {
>             RadioButton r = dr.Cells[0].Controls[0] as RadioButton;
>             if (r.Checked)
>                 radioValue = r.Text;
>         }
>     }
>     return radioValue;
> }
> ```